# conditional expectation wrt a family of rv

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation

both $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ (the index set $I$ is uncountable) and $\xi$ are integrable r.v. in $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$

how to prove: there is a countable subet $J\subset I$ s.t. 
$$\mathbb E[\xi|\sigma(X_i,i\in I)]=\mathbb E[\xi|\sigma(X_i,i\in J)]\tag{1}$$

$\sigma(X_i,i\in I)$ means the $\sigma-$algebra generate by $(X_i,i\in I)$

I think the only tool I can use is the monotone class theorem for functions, so I collect all the rv $\xi$ that satisfy (1) to a set $\mathcal H$, if we can prove $\mathcal H$ contains all the measurable functions, then we get the conclusion.

but I finially found it doesn't solve the problem, since I can't fine why $(1)$ holds for indicator function $1_A$, where $A\in\mathcal F$.

Comment: There is no $Y$ in your eq. 1!

Comment: @iiivooo I updated my question.

Comment: Just to be clear, by  $\mathbb E[\xi|X_i,i\in I]$ do you mean conditioning by the sigma algebra generated by all $X_i,i\in I$ ? another important question is how you measure the distance between two random variables? (= what is the space we are working on, $L^1$, $L^2$?)

Comment: @iiivooo the answer is yes and $L^1$(it is necessary by the definition of conditional expectation)

Comment: Why delete the input? Now this is 100% PSQ.

Comment: @Did what does PSQ mean? I deleted what I have tried because it seems that nobody understand what I have done.

Comment: Bad decision. // Re PSQ, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/common-acronyms-used-on-main-and-meta

Answer (score 0):

**Just an idea:**

If $X_i \in L^2$ then using the fact that $L^2$ is separable Hilbert space there exist countable subset $J$ such that for any $Y \in L^2$
$$Y=\sum_{j \in J} \langle Y,X_j \rangle X_j$$
from this it should be possible to deduce that
$$\sigma\left( X_i,i \in I\right) = \sigma\left( X_j,j \in I\right).$$